# Model accessible to all other classes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

To access a model in another controller, currently I use the `$this->loadModel('Setting')` command within the class.
I want my model "Settings" be accessible by any other class, without requiring that I use all the time `$this->loadModel('Setting')`, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, CakePHP will automatically load the Model that 'fits' the controllername (e.g. the `Post` model will automatically loaded for the `PostsController`).

That is, if you *didn't specify which models to load*.

### Manually specifying which Models to load in a Controller

As with most things in CakePHP, You can override this by manually overriding the 'automatic' settings; you can specify which models are to be used in a Controller via the `$uses` property;

```
public $uses = array(
    'ModelA',
    'ModelB',
);
```

This will load 'ModelA' and 'ModelB' in the Controller, which will be accessible via `$this->ModelA` and `$this->ModelB` inside the Controller.

The `$uses` property of a Controller will be **merged** with the `$uses` property of the AppModel, so if you add the `Setting` model to the `$uses` of your AppController, then it will be automatically loaded in **every Controller that extends the AppController**

Read the documentation: [The App Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller)

### Ad-Hoc accessing a Model

If you need to access a Model *anywhere* in your project, but mainly if you only need to access if in certain conditions or inside a specific action, you can initiate a model via the `ClassRegistry`;

For example;

```
 $ModelA = ClassRegistry::init('ModelA');
```

Or, if you just need some data from the model, but don't need if after that;

```
 $projects = ClassRegistry::init('Project')->find('list');
```